# How to turn pasta sauce into a longer-lasting ketchup?

Tags: food-preservation

I was making a bacon sandwich earlier and I have some nice jars of tomato pasta sauce in the cupboard. I thought it'd make a great relish but it would go off too quickly in the fridge to make i economical. It got me wondering whether there's anything you can do to make an existing tomato sauce into a something with a longer shelf life.

For example, could you add vinegar or salt to tip the sauce over into more of a preserved sauce?

Similar question might apply to salsas, I suppose?

Comment: Your best bet is probably simply to freeze the leftovers in suitably-sized portions.

Comment: @ChrisH That makes sense, actually! Good thought... I should half-inch some of those paper cups from MacDonalds and put them in the freezer.

Answer (score 1):

Ketchup keeps because it is full of sugar (reduces water activity) and vinegar (acid, keeps microbes and especially molds at bay). A boatload of both. Look at a ketchup recipe for reference...

Comment: That makes sense. I think the right way to do it would be to use both, finding a balance between the sweet and sour. But then, if it proves too complicated, I might as well make my own ketchup; can't be too hard!